# play audio using different swift file

Tags: swift, xcode, avplayer, avaudioplayer

below is the code representing a file for an audio player. I'm trying to utilize it for playing sounds in my program. I don't want to put a AVPlayer function in every view controller to play repeatable sounds, so I'm looking for a way to put everything in one place and call to the specific function (music, click, intro) when needed

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class player: UIViewController
{
var music:Bool = true
var sound:Bool = true
var intro:Bool = true

var soundPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
var clickPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
var musicPlayer : AVAudioPlayer?
{
    get
    {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        return appDelegate.musicPlayer
    }
    set
    {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.musicPlayer = newValue
    }
}

func playSound(title: String, format: String)
{
    if sound == true
    {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: title, withExtension: format)

            else { return }

        do
        {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            soundPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)

            soundPlayer?.play()
        }
        catch let error
        {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

func playClick()
{
    if sound == true
    {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "click", withExtension: "mp3")

            else { return }

        do
        {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            let clickPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)

            clickPlayer.play()
        }
        catch let error
        {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

func playMusic()
{
    if music == true
    {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ambientMusic", withExtension: "mp3")

            else { return }

        do
        {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            musicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)

            musicPlayer?.play()
            musicPlayer?.numberOfLoops = -1
        }
        catch let error
        {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Different file:

```
@IBAction func play(_ sender: Any)
{
    player().playClick()
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menuToIntro", sender: self)
}
```

But it doesn't play anything. Just prints log **AQDefaultDevice (173): skipping input stream 0 0 0x0**

Answer (score 1):

From discussion [here](https://github.com/muhku/FreeStreamer/issues/313) this is a bug with the Xcode simulator and you should try going to Edit Scheme > Run > Arguments and 
adding environment variable OS_ACTIVITY_MODE, value disable.

Comment: well, I got rid of logs inside the console yes but it doesn't solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found an issue. It is necessary in my case to store a player as a property or other variable that won't get destroyed. That's why the logs - sound was played but immediately terminated. I fixed it by declaring AVAudioPlayers in AppDelegate